# Can't import android.nfc.NfcAdapter

Tags: android, nfc

I'm trying to import `android.nfc.NfcAdapter` class in my project, but Android Studio can't see it. These are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.TangemCash:card-common:v0.2.2'
    implementation 'com.github.TangemCash:card-android:v0.2.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

And this is my manifest:

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />

        </activity>
```

And `nfc_tech_filter.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

I'm not sure what to do next. Idea says `Unresolved reference nfc` whenever I try to import `android.nfc.NfcAdapter` What is wrong?